# SyntaxError keeps appearing

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to enter code for a Discord bot (specifically to see the servers it's in) and I keep getting the same error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log("Servers:")
   client.guilds.forEach((guild) => {
      console.log(" - " + guild.name)
   })
})

client.login("NzAwNTU3ODYwMDY4Nzg2MTc2.XriCJA.nZeS_pxvwfVDJ062IoaXa8NVDfM")
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You may have to update Node.js to a more recent version, I guess.

Comment: your syntax error is somewhere else

Comment: error should contain file name and line (this part is ok)

Comment: Please post the entire error message (including traceback) and your entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line containing `client.guilds.forEach`, you need to add `.cache` before `.forEach`. In v12+ of discord.js it is written like that.
The resulting code should look like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log("Servers:")
   client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
      console.log(" - " + guild.name)
   })
})

client.login("NzAwNTU3ODYwMDY4Nzg2MTc2.XriCJA.nZeS_pxvwfVDJ062IoaXa8NVDfM")
```